# Rake not recognizing .ssh/config file

Tags: ruby, rake

Hi guys I have been searching for the solution and while it is probably something obvious it is escaping me.

I am trying to use rake to run some tasks over ssh via the system command but it doesn't recognize my .ssh/config file.

For example:

```
task :my_task
  system("ssh myserver 'command on myserver'")
end
```

This gives me the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver: Name or service not known
```

When I run the command from the command line outside of rake it runs fine.

It also works when tested in irb:

```
system "ssh myserver 'command on myserver'"
```

Any ideas on what (probably completely obvious thing) I am missing with rake?

Comment: What does it do, when you pass the configuration file with the `-F` parameter?

Comment: The -F parameter? What/where do I use it?

Comment: `ssh -f config_file_path` where *config_file_path* is the path to your ssh configuration file, typically `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` is really ornery and will ignore things it doesn't think are "secure enough", so you may have a valid file but invalid permissions.

A quick fix is usually:

```
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it didn't do the trick. I keep thinking it has to be something with how rake handles system(ssh) since the command runs fine outside of rake.

Comment: You could try engaging `-v` for more verbose output to see how your request is handled.

Comment: I messed around some more with permissions and it seems like your original idea was correct. Thanks so much for the help! Sorry to waste so much time.

Comment: Not a waste of time if you got it working. No trouble. `ssh`, at times, is like a fussy kid that won't touch their dinner if the peas are in contact with the potatoes.